# Can I take a webcam picture without activating the webcam LED?

Tags: webcam, ffmpeg

Both `ffmpeg` and `fswebcam` are triggering the LED of most laptop webcam.

I am wondering if there were a way to take a picture without activating the LED or if it was simply impossible to do so (I am not clear how the LED is activating electronically).

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no way to prevent it. It's there as some sort of "safety" feature. I recommend just putting electrical tape over the LED. Unfortunately, the LEDs most often are triggered when power is applied to the camera (which has to be applied in order to take the picture)